# Why does this google app script taking forever to run? What is slowing it down?

Tags: google-apps-script

Why does this code taking forever to run? What is slowing it down?

```
function Refresh(e){
     var e=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var formulaSheet = e.getSheetByName("John");
     var formulaCell = formulaSheet.getRange(2,5);
     formulaCell.setValue(formulaCell.getFormula().replace("USD","USE"));
     formulaCell.setValue(formulaCell.getFormula().replace("USE","USD"));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Something was wrong my browser, I cleared cache and it is much quicker now